# Check User has Full Control Site Permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, office-365, rest

Is there away to check if a user has Full Control permissions with out throwing an exception?
I've tried the following using REST:

> https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/test/_api/web/doesuserhavepermissions(@v)?@v={'High':'2147483647', 'Low':'4294967295'}

I get the following:

> {
>   error: {
>   code: "-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException"
>   message: {
>   lang: "en-US"
>   value: "Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."
>   }-
>   }-
>   }

Comment: You mention below in a comment that you are doing this via a console application. What method are you using to connect to the server? Make sure you are sending valid credentials with that request.

Comment: When checking currentUser permissions is there a difference between SCA rights and Full control, when checking the IsSiteAdmin field? If yes, what api do I need to check for full control?

Answer (score 1):

If the current user has not enough permission then you won't be able to check the permission itself.

The best option is to run the permission check in APP context.

Comment: The account is a Global Admin, I'm doing this from a console application. Is there any other way?

Comment: I would of thought a Global Admin would have enough permissions to at least perform a check?

Comment: What kind of [App Authorization Policy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179892.aspx) are you using, do you know? If you're making the request from an **App-only** policy, "Authorization check succeeds only if the current app has sufficient permissions to perform the action in question, regardless of the permissions of the current user (if any)."

Comment: @AmalHashim, can you expand on what you mean by "run the permission check in APP context"? Perhaps some code would be helpful?

Answer (score 1):

If user is Global admin then you can check user permission programmatically:

```
SPUser currentUser = null;
using (SPSite spSite = SPContext.Current.Site)
{
    using (SPWeb web = spSite.OpenWeb())
    {                        
        currentUser = web.CurrentUser;                        
        bool isSiteAdmin = currentUser.IsSiteAdmin;
        if (isSiteAdmin)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(currentUser + " has Full Control.");
        }
    }
}
```